# Within a .vcxproj file what are the possible values for the <ConfigurationType> and what do those values mean?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5, vcxproj

Within a .vcxproj file what are the possible values for the ConfigurationType and what do those values mean? -Or- where can I find this information on MSDN? I have had difficulty sellecting a good search string to answer my question.

I think I know the answer to the first question, but I want confirmation/ details.

Here is what I think I know:

- **Application** produces an exe.
- **DynamicLibrary** produces a .lib and a .dll file. (Follow up here, if that is true then does it always produce both? or are there
  exceptions that produce one or the other. Perhaps I am accidentally thinking of c++/cli? Is there a different possibility in a c++/cli file? )

Are those correct, are there any others?

Comment: It binds to Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine.ConfigurationType.  So StaticLibrary, MakeFile and Utility are the other ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just open the dropdown menu within Visual Studio project properties to get the list... but [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x480de8.aspx) is the MSDN documentation.

> There are several configuration types from which to
>   choose: **Application** (.exe), displays linker toolset (C/C++ Compiler,
>   MIDL, Resource Compiler, Linker, BSCMake, XML Web Service Proxy
>   Generator, custom build, prebuild, prelink, postbuild events). **Dynamic
>   Library** (.dll), displays linker toolset, specifies /DLL linker option,
>   and adds the _WINDLL define to CL. **Makefile**, displays makefile toolset
>   (NMake). **Static Library** (.lib), displays librarian toolset (same as
>   linker toolset except substitute librarian for linker and omit XML Web
>   Service Proxy Generator). **Utility**, displays utility toolset (MIDL,
>   custom build, prebuild, postbuild events).